# Trouble getting desired json output with JacksonJaxbJsonProvider

Tags: json, jaxb, jackson, cxf

I'm using the latest Jackson (2.2.3) with a CXF application.

Here is my Jackson provider:

```
public class CustomJacksonJsonProvider extends JacksonJaxbJsonProvider {
    public CustomJacksonJsonProvider() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        JaxbAnnotationModule jaxbModule = new JaxbAnnotationModule();
        mapper.registerModule(jaxbModule);
        this._mapperConfig.setMapper(mapper);
    }
}
```

I have the following annotated class.

```
@XmlType(name = "configInfo")
@XmlRootElement(name = "configInfo")
public class ConfigInfo {
    @XmlElement(name = "foo")
    private String  foo;
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "devices")
    @XmlElement(name = "device")
    private List<Device>    devices;

    public final List<Device> getDevices() {
        if (devices == null)
            devices = new ArrayList<Device>();
        return devices;
    }
}
```

I created an instance with no "foo" value, and one device in the devices list.  When I render this, I get the following:

```
{"device":[{"name":"abc","type":"def"}]}
```

How can I make "device" render as "devices"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to figure this out.  The key realization is that if the JAXB annotations are confusing Jackson, then perhaps I should just have Jackson ignore them.  I simply removed the registration of the "JaxbAnnotationModule" and now both my JSON and XML output are sane.  I now need to consider whether it makes any sense to use "JacksonJaxbJsonProvider" as opposed to a simpler provider.